# Files uploaded using Oauth 2.0 service account do not appear

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Trying to use [Oauth 2.0 server to server authentication](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) (using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts))  to upload a file to google drive. Have used their sample code as a reference, the resulting script is something like this:

```py
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def main(argv):
    # Load the key in PKCS 12 format that you downloaded from the Google API
    # Console when you created your Service account.
    f = open('key.p12', 'rb')
    key = f.read()
    f.close()

    # Check https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes for all available scopes
    OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

    # Path to the file to upload
    FILENAME = 'testfile.txt'

    # Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
    # with the Credentials. Note that the first parameter, service_account_name,
    # is the Email address created for the Service account. It must be the email
    # address associated with the key that was created.
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        'xxxxx-xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        key,
        OAUTH_SCOPE)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

    # Insert a file
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
    body = {
        'title': 'My document',
        'description': 'A test document',
        'mimeType': 'text/plain'
    }

    fil = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
    pprint.pprint(fil)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main(sys.argv)
```

The script seems to run ok (no errors, pprint shows output that seems to be fine). However the google drive page for the account does not show the uploaded file. When trying to access one of the links from the pprint output to see the file I get a "You need permission" message from Google Drive, which is weird, as I am logged to the account in which I created the service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is owned by the service account, not your Google account. Service accounts have their own 5gb of space for Google Drive.

You'll need to either share the file with your user account or have the service account [impersonate your user account](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) (assuming you're in a Google Apps domain) so that the file is created and owned by your user account.

Comment: I just want to upload files to the drive account with a script without having to authorize every time this is required (and without putting the username and password in the script). I am not using Google Apps. Am I out of luck?

Comment: No, you aren't out of luck, just use the normal OAuth 2.0 Web flow, you only need to go through the flow once and it will store a refresh token that will get used every time after that. The easiest way to get started would be to use https://developers.google.com/quickstart/, select the Drive API and the Python|Command-Line platform and it will create a skeleton application that will what you want, just add your service.files().insert(...) code above to the generated skeleton.

Comment: The relevant Quickstart guide for Python is here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-python